# Radio button values as integers in Twig

Tags: twig, twig-extension

This is my code for generating a radio_button question;

```
{{ question.min_text }}
{% for i in question.min..question.max %}
    {{ form_radio(question.slug, i) }} {{ i }} <br>
{% endfor %}
{{ question.max_text }}
```

The values here are all coming out as strings. How can I force them to be integers?

I am using Twig Bridge by the way if that makes a difference.

Update - This is the view-source of one of the radio buttons;

```
<input name="a_question" type="radio" value="3">
```

Shouldn't it be;

```
<input name="a_question" type="radio" value=3>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "they are all coming out as strings"?

Comment: That's right. HTML and HTTP do not know anything about strings or integers (that's why the Symfony `ParameterBag` class offers methods like `getInt()`, for example). The data is transformed implictly by the Form component through data transformers during form submission.